# Python, Não consigo dar select no mysql.connector

Tags: mysql, python, banco-de-dados, sql-select

Eu estou usando uma máquina virtual Ubuntu, instalei o mysql.connector e tentei rodar o seguinte código:

```py
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="registration", password="senha", database="registration");

cur = mydb.cursor(buffered=True);

temp = cur.execute("select * from temp_token;").fetchall();
```

Mas quando eu tento rodar o código, tudo que recebo é o erro:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'
```

A tabela na base de dados tem entradas sim. O comando que eu digitei ali dá um retorno perfeito no cliente mysql. Então por que não está retornando nada? É como se ele conseguisse *aplicar* o comando, mas não conseguisse *ler* nada.

A pior parte é que no mesmo script eu uso "insert" para inserir na base de dados e funciona **perfeitamente**!

OBS: mey python é 3.8.10 e a máquina virtual do Ubuntu é 20.04

Answer (score 1):

Tenta da seguinte maneira.

```
temp = cur.execute("select * from temp_token")
result_fetched = cur.fetchall()

for i in result_fetched:
   print(i)
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muito obrigado! Ajudou muito!

Answer (score 1):

`.execute()` apenas executa a consulta e não retorna nada.
Depende de você como você vai buscar os resultados *(ex: iterator, fetchall(), fetchone() etc.)*

```
  cursor.execute(sql_list_schemas)
  list_schemas = cursor.fetchall()
```

--

Veja um código similar

```
 cursor.execute(sql_list_schemas)

 remaining_rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Utilizando seu próprio código eu modificaria para isso:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="registration", password="senha", database="registration");

cur = mydb.cursor(buffered=True);

cur.execute("select * from temp_token")

temp = cur.fetchall()

print(temp)
```

Comment: Ahhh! Entendi! Muito obrigado mesmo!